# Not understanding how to use selenium for truecaller

Tags: python, selenium

I have written a python code to automatically log into truecaller, search for a number and then scrape the results.I am successfully able to log in and then search for the number but I am not really able to understand the flow of the program.
Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# Initializing firefox browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
# Initializing login to google
browser.get('https://www.truecaller.com/sign-in/google')
browser.find_element_by_id('Email').send_keys('email')
browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd').send_keys('password');
browser.find_element_by_id('signIn').click();
# nice 1 gets printed immediately
print "nice1"
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'submit_approve_access')))
# by clicking on element we are clicking on the "allow " button of the google authorization page
element.click();
# nice 2 takes a little while to get printed
print "nice2"
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 0.1).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS, "detailView__nameText")))
except:
    browser.get("https://www.truecaller.com/in/9882541575")
```

Now since after clicking the sign-in button,the page redirects so I have written the wait block to wait for the new page to appear so as to click the "Allow" button there.
Everything works fine but I have a simple doubt.When the sign-in button is clicked,"nice 1" gets printed immediately but when the submit_approve_access or the allow button is clicked,the "nice 2" takes a little while to get printed instead of being printed immediately unlike the previous case where the sign in button was clicked and the "nice 1" was printed immediately.Because of that the following try/except block goes to waste.Please help me in understanding the flow of the program.Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please could you edit this or refocus your question so we can be clear what your problem is? You say you wrote this code but seem to think we will understand it better than you!

Comment: Sorry Sir for the ambiguity in question.I had printed two strings named "nice 1" and "nice 2" out of which the earlier one was printed almost immediately but the second one took some time.I wanted the reason for that.It's because of the fact that the first page loaded very fast in comparison to second and hence the difference in printing of the two strings.

Comment: Hey Abhishek, I am trying to do something similar. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @IrshadWhat problem are you facing?

Comment: the url given in this above code is giving a 404 error. this code might not work now..

Answer (score 1):

I think the "nice 1" is not printed immediately. You see it is printed immediately because the page is loaded very fast. However, the next page that you print "nice 2" is very slow.

The WebDriver automatically waits for page loaded before printing both "nice 1" and "nice 2". As far as I know, when we use driver.get() or driver.click() on a hyperlink or a button that submits form, Selenium WebDriver will automatically wait until page load. The timeout setting for this is called "pageLoadTimeout".

See the class at [Selenium API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information .I understand the reason now.Gonna look into the pageLoadTimeout class.Again thanks for giving your precious time.